# Should I add .docpad.db to my .gitignore?

Tags: docpad

I've been using [DocPad](http://docpad.org/) for a while now and just upgraded to version 6.55.5 and I now have a new file `.docpad.db`. I can't seem to find any information about this online.

**Should I commit this into source control or ignore it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a new file that is automatically generated to serve as a cache for the DocPad database. Unfortunatelly, git doesn't automatically ignore all dot files.

It is perfectly safe to put it in your gitignore file, and considering it is a cache file, it is probably recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a file that you explicitly created and want to track, don't ignore it. Check it in. If it's an automatically generated file which you don't care about, ignore it.